# Two authors on the same line on the titlepage

Tags: titles

How can I put two authors in the titlepage? I tried this but it didnt work (nothing showed up after the title):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\stackMath
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    space \\
    [10cm]
    \huge{Some title in swedish here}\\
    [1cm]   
    \author{
  Name Surname\\
  \texttt{emailh@outlook.com}
  \and
  Name Surname\\
  \texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
}
\date{} 


    \end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

EDIT 2:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\stackMath
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx} 



\title{\huge Titel \\[1cm]}
\author{&
  Name Surname\\
  \texttt{emailh@outlook.com}
  \and
  Name Surname\\
  \texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
}
\date{} 



\begin{document}
%{\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
%\maketitle 

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage




\section*{Table of contents}

\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example isn't compilable

Comment: I am sorry. I will try to find the error.

Comment: Oh I forgot \begin{document}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean this?

The `titlepage` option enables the `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}` environment for the `\maketitle` command and has a bigger top space (before the title.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\stackMath
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\title{\huge Some title in swedish here \\[1cm]}
\author{%
  Name Surname\\
  \texttt{emailh@outlook.com}
  \and
  Name Surname\\
  \texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
}
\date{} 


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

```
\documentclass[11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{abraces}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\stackMath
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx} 



\title{\huge Titel \\[1cm]}
\author{%  ---> & wrong here!!!
  Name Surname\\
  \texttt{emailh@outlook.com}
  \and
  Name Surname\\
  \texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
}
\date{} 



\begin{document}
%{\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\maketitle 

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage




\section*{Table of contents}

\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to have one page dedicated to title and two authors. But it looks like I dont know how to put this thing on one page and everything else after. (I am writing a report) Sorry for my english.

Comment: @Rectifier: This is one page ... I don't understand. What is `everything` ???

Comment: @Rectifier: The second page has the table of contents... this nothing what is meant for the titlepage

Comment: I will paste my code here in a second. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: :I have edited the original post and added my code right now. The title does not show up at all.

Comment: @Rectifier: Yes, you edited the post away from the original question, making the efforts so far basically useless :-(

Comment: I am sorry, I guess that I ruined this thread. Thank you for the help anyways.

Comment: @Rectifier: Correcting the wrong `&` in `\author` and `titlepage` option to your edited code all is there as expected. Give it a try

Comment: @Rectifier: Alright: Happy TeXing then ;-)